# HtmlAgilityPack: Взять всех непосредственных потомков элемента

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Доброго времени суток.

Мне нужно получить всех непосредственных потомков для данного узла в список. Как это можно сделать в HtmlAgilityPack?

Пример:
Допустим есть некая структура

```
body
    h1
    p
    h2
    p
       a
    p
       br
    p
       a
```

Как мне выбрать все узлы которые вложены непосредственно в body? (т.е. a и br сюда не подходят)

Comment: На сайте уже есть ответы по htmlagilitypack, среди них искали ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Я бы установил расширение из NuGet `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` и использовал обычный css selector `var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("body > *");` и далее `foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes) { ... }`, а без расширения только через XPath `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(...)`

Comment: @tym32167 Ответа на свой вопрос я не нашёл.. Как выбрать дочерний элемент - да. Но вот как оформить в список все дочерние узлы первого поколения я не могу понять

Comment: Берем `body` - `//`, далее нужны все объекты, что есть в нем - `*`, получаем `//body/*`, для получения списка нод есть метд `SelectNodes`. Вроде все просто, не?

Comment: По сути тут вопрос только в составлении верного xpath, который выше уже подсказали.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ааа понял, сейчас попробую

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я торопыга и бракодел) `node.Descendants()` как раз таки и возьмёт первый уровень и у переменной в которую мы положим результат будет тип `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` а это то что нужно. Только что обратил внимание на отладчик. В итоге никакого XPath не нужно.

Comment: @JohnnyRage может ответом оформите? Это может быть полезно для других участников.

Comment: Да, позже оформлю. Сейчас просто немного голова от задачи текущей пухнет. Куча всего вылезает и чёт грустняшку словил от этого. Разгребаю вот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы взять всех детей текущего узла достаточно прописать `node.ChildNodes`

например есть следующее дерево

```
body
h1
p
h2
p
   a
p
   br
p
   a
```

Чтобы из данного дерева выбрать всех потомков первого поколения(т.е. всё что НЕ `а` и не `br`) нужно установить значение узла

```
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
var nodes = node.ChildNodes;
```

тогда мы  в `nodes` получим все элементы из `body`.